# How can I use the function of one component in another component? (react)

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

I want to use a function `setCount()` in the class `Footer` in another component. But I get an error that I do not know why.
class Footer:

```
export default class Footer extends Component {
    setCount()
        {
            //code
           }
    

    render() {
        return (
<div >
//code
        
</div>
        );
    }
}
```

class TodoItem:

```
import footer from "./Footer"


@observer
class TodoItem extends Component {
   

  ontoggle=()=>{
    this.props.todo.toggle();
    footer.setCount() //this line get an error
   
  }
  render(){
    const {todo} =this.props
  
      return(

       //code

      )
  }
}
```

type error: `TypeError: _Footer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.setCount is not a function`

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you can tell what do you wanna do, many people here would suggest good ideas on how to accomplish your goal with best practices, but if you just wanna learn this I suggest that you follow design pattern. For this instance you can check this [link](https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/design-patterns/builder) to learn more about Builders.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `setCount` method as static in order to make it work. However, a static method cannot access `this` keyword.